# AngularJS вложенный $http запрос. Повтор запроса до получения нужного ответа

Tags: angularjs, http, рекурсия, promise

Есть некий сервис, отсылает запрос на сервер.

```
angular
    .module('lessonApp')
    .service('sendJson', [
        '$http',
        function($http) {
            this.startJson = function (url) {
                var startJson={
                    "operation": "start",
                    "task": "1"
                };
                var promise = $http({
                    url: url,
                    method: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify(startJson),
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'}
                }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                    console.log(response.data);
                }, function errorCallback() {
                    alert("Ошибка");
                });
                return promise;
            };
        }
    ]);
```

Вот его вызываем и после ответа выводим все успешно:

```
sendJson.startJson(url).then(function (response) {
                alert('Запрос вернул ответ');
            });
```

Но нужно изменить код, после успешного ответа от сервера нужно посылать другой запрос на сервер периодически до того времени пока не придет нужный ответ. То есть запрос должен повторятся и когда придет нужный ответ уже возвращать это.
Например

```
    var promise = $http({
                        url: url,
                        method: "POST",
                        data: JSON.stringify(startJson),
                        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'}
                    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                        console.log(response.data);
//???
    var resultJS={
                        "operation": "result",
                        "task": "1"
                    };
               var resultExist=false;
                    while (resultExist==false) {
                        var promiseResult = $http({
                            url: url,
                            method: "POST",
                            data: JSON.stringify(resultJS),
                            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'}
                        }).then(function successCallback(responseResult) {
                            if(responseResult.data.status=='done')
                                resultExist=true;
                        },function errorCallback() {
                            alert("resultJS error");
                        });
                        return promiseResult;
                    }
//???
                    }, function errorCallback() {
                        alert("Ошибка");
                    });
                    return promise;
```

Вынес вложенный запрос в отдельный файл-сервис, если первый запрос успешный исполняем второй

```
angular
    .module('lessonApp')
    .service('resultJson', [
        '$http',
        function($http) {
            this.getResultJson = function (url) {
                var resultJson={
                    "operation": "result",
                    "task": "1",
                };
                var promise = $http({
                    url: url,
                    method: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify(resultJson),
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'}
                }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                    if(response.data.status=='in proccess'){
                        self.getResultJson(url); //подправил
                    }else{ return 'done';}
                }, function errorCallback() {
                    alert("Ошибка");
                });
                return promise;
            };
        }
    ]);
```

Рекурсия кажется работает, но как правильно возвращать `promise`?

Comment: рекурсия вам поможет :-)

Comment: Если рекурсия, так ли это должно быть как я добавил в шапку? Если да, то как обратится запросу к самому себе? И вернет ли в этом случае promise то что нужно?

Comment: Небольшое замечание. За каким чертом вы посылаете на сервер JSON, снабдив его заголовком `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`? У JSON медиа-тип совсем другой, `application/json`.

Comment: Я сам не знаю, много мучался с хэадерами, но только этот отсылает нормально на сервер запрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем виде асинхронный цикл на js через рекурсию делается так:

```
function foo() {
    return какойтаАсинхронныйВызов()
      .then(function(result) {
          if (какие-то условие)
              return foo()
          else
              return result;
      })
}
```

Вовсе не обязательно выносить такой вызов в отдельный сервис - достаточно асинхронной функции.

Кстати, я бы не рекомендовал указывать `errorCallback` для каждого вызова `then` - если нужно просто показать сообщение пользователю, то достаточно обработать ошибку всего один раз, в самом конце.

Если же задача состоит в том, чтобы "проглотить" ошибку (и уйти на другую итерацию цикла) - не надо при этом показывать сообщение пользователю:

```
function foo() {
    return какойтаАсинхронныйВызов()
      .then(function(result) {
          if (какие-то условие)
              return foo()
          else
              return result;
      }, function() {
          return foo()
      })
}
```

PS
Краткий ответ

> Рекурсия кажется работает, но как правильно возвращать promise?

Через `return`.

Comment: мне кажется стоит P.S. в самое начало перенести :-D